# RestKit : how to map an array with correct type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit-0.20

Got:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *user;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *token;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *list;// NSNumber only please!
```

And:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyResponse class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"user" : @"user",
    @"token" : @"token",
    @"list" : @"list",
 }];
```

And I receive Json:

```
{"user":"foobar","token":"azerty","list":[0,1,"2"]}
```

Unfortunately, `list` will be a mix of NSString and NSNumber. How to tell RestKit 0.2x I only want NSNumber or NSString in my NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rewriting a JSON parser to do your particular task, why not just post-process 'list' and check each object with `if([list[i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])` and convert it to an NSNumber?

Comment: Annoying, I didn't know RestKit was so useless for basic mapping. So, everywhere a `MyResponse` object is the result of a RKObjectRequestOperation, I had to: `response.list = [response.list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [NSNumber self]]];`

Answer (score 2):

`RestKit` uses KVC so surely if you just want numbers you could use the appropriate keyPath e.g. if I wanted the numbers to always be integers I could use the method `integerValue` which both `NSNumber` and `NSString` have:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyResponse class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
  @"user"              : @"user",
  @"token"             : @"token",
  @"list.integerValue" : @"list",
}];
```

Comment: Exception raised when it's an NSArray or NSDictionary. Totally unsafe.

Comment: @cœur if your data is that irregular then you are not going to have any fun with a framework like `RestKit`